# How do I return 0 instead of #Error?

Tags: reporting-services

I have the following expression.

```
=Fields!AvgLOSC4.Value.Split("|"c)(0)
```

Occasionally, it returns `#Error` instead of a value. If the above expression results in an error, how do return `0` instead of displaying `#Error`?

Answer (score 1):

`Split` or `IIf` checks won't work as SSRS doesn't short circuit on these and if any part fails the whole expression errors.

You can get around this with custom code. Add the following code to your report:

```
Function FirstSplit(fieldValue As String) As String
  If IsDBNull(fieldValue) OrElse IsNothing(fieldValue) Then
    FirstSplit = "0"
  Else
    FirstSplit = fieldValue.Split("|")(0)
  End If
End Function
```

Call the code in a cell with:

```
=Code.FirstSplit(Fields!AvgLOSC4.Value)
```

With a Dataset generated by:

```
select AvgLOSC4 = '1|2'
union all select AvgLOSC4 = '1'
union all select AvgLOSC4 = null
```

You can generate a report like:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Check if the Field is `NULL` before splitting the value

```
=Iif(IsNothing(Fields!AvgLOSC4.Value),"Display NULL",
                                      Fields!AvgLOSC4.Value.Split("|"c)(0))
```

Comment: This isn't working. I'm still getting `#Error`. What could be causing `.Value` to have a value but still generate the #Error?